# Reversing constrained PCA Regressions while maintaining constraint

Tags: pca, data-transformation, optimization, constrained-regression

I have an input matrix X that is 1000x10 and a response Y.  To reduce the dimensions, I run PCA, select a certain number of factors (say 2) and transform my X to now be 1000x2.  I then scale Y and run a constrained regression to force all my Beta's to sum to one, easily done by solving through quadratic programming.

My question is, if you care about the original X's, say in portfolio construction, is there a way to reverse those Betas back out while maintaining some of the original constraint?

So in essence, given:
$$
\hat Y'= B_1 \hat x_1'+B_2 \hat x_2', \\
{\rm s.t.}\quad B_1 + B_2 = 1
$$
I would like to undo the transformation so that I get weights for the original 10 x inputs, hopefully while maintaining some sense of the constraint.  This could be equated to construct a market neutral portfolio Z dollars of Y and a total of Z dollars across all X's

Comment: I don't understand why there's a question here, so I likely am misreading something.  You have told us that $$x_1^\prime=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\alpha_i x_i$$ for coefficients $\alpha_i$ (which you chose) and similarly the vector $x_2^\prime$ is a linear combination of the $x_i$, say with coefficients $\beta_i$.  Therefore the coefficient of $x_i$ in your fitted model is $C_i=B_1\alpha_i+B_2\beta_i$. Is that what you mean by "undo the transformation"? And if you arrange for $\sum_i\alpha_i=\sum_i\beta_i=1$, wouldn't that "maintain some sense of the constraint" by automatically assuring $\sum_i C_i=1$?